# Compare two dataframes row wise using udf (using library whoswho)

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions, string-comparison

I've two Spark dataframes with names and want to compare these row wise using the Python library `[whoswho][1]`

How can I create a UDF with a row wise comparison? (or a better way to compare using the `whoswho` library)

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
 ["Luc Krier"],
 ["Jeanny Thorn"],
 ["Teddy E Beecher"],
 ["Philippe Schauss"],
 ["Meindert I Tholen"],
 ["John I Muller"]
]).toDF("name")

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
 ["J. Thorn"],
 ["Ben Weller"],
 ["L. Krier"],
 ["J.M. Thorn"],
 ["Liam Muller"],
 ["Meindert Tholen"]
]).toDF("name")
```

Sample using whoswho:

```
from whoswho import who
who.match('Luc Krier', 'L. Krier')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only intend to filter the `True` results from `whoswho`

You can cross-join the rows of the dataframes and create a `UDF` with `who.match` and finally filter on only the `True` results

#### Data Preparation

```
df1 = sql.createDataFrame([
 ["Luc Krier"],
 ["Jeanny Thorn"],
 [ "Teddy E Beecher"],
 ["Philippe Schauss"],
 ["Meindert I Tholen"],
 ["John I Muller"]
]).toDF("name")

df2 = sql.createDataFrame([
 ["J. Thorn"],
 ["Ben Weller"],
 [ "L. Krier"],
 ["J.M. Thorn"],
 ["Liam Muller"],
 ["Meindert Tholen"]
]).toDF("name")


df1 = df1.withColumn('id',F.lit(1))
df2 = df2.withColumn('id',F.lit(1))

combined_df = df1.join(df2
                      ,df1['id'] == df2['id']
                      ).select(df1['name'],df2['name'].alias('name_proxy'))

#### 20 records
combined_df.show()

+----------------+---------------+
|            name|     name_proxy|
+----------------+---------------+
|       Luc Krier|       J. Thorn|
|       Luc Krier|     Ben Weller|
|       Luc Krier|       L. Krier|
|    Jeanny Thorn|       J. Thorn|
|    Jeanny Thorn|     Ben Weller|
|    Jeanny Thorn|       L. Krier|
| Teddy E Beecher|       J. Thorn|
| Teddy E Beecher|     Ben Weller|
| Teddy E Beecher|       L. Krier|
|       Luc Krier|     J.M. Thorn|
|       Luc Krier|    Liam Muller|
|       Luc Krier|Meindert Tholen|
|    Jeanny Thorn|     J.M. Thorn|
|    Jeanny Thorn|    Liam Muller|
|    Jeanny Thorn|Meindert Tholen|
| Teddy E Beecher|     J.M. Thorn|
| Teddy E Beecher|    Liam Muller|
| Teddy E Beecher|Meindert Tholen|
|Philippe Schauss|       J. Thorn|
|Philippe Schauss|     Ben Weller|
+----------------+---------------+
```

#### Pandas UDF

```
from whoswho import who
from functools import partial,reduce

schema = StructType([
           StructField('name', StringType(), True),
           StructField('name_proxy', StringType(), True),
           StructField('match', BooleanType(), True)
 ])

def whos_who_match(inp_df,match_columns):
    
    inp_df['match'] = inp_df[match_columns].apply(lambda x : who.match(x[0],x[1]),axis=1)
    
    return inp_df

partial_func = partial(whos_who_match,match_columns=['name','name_proxy'])

combined_df = combined_df.groupby('name').applyInPandas(partial_func,schema)

combined_df.filter(F.col('match') == True).show()

+-----------------+---------------+-----+
|             name|     name_proxy|match|
+-----------------+---------------+-----+
|Meindert I Tholen|Meindert Tholen| true|
|     Jeanny Thorn|       J. Thorn| true|
|        Luc Krier|       L. Krier| true|
+-----------------+---------------+-----+
```

#### UDF

```
from whoswho import who

@F.udf(BooleanType())
def whos_who_match(x,y):
    return who.match(x,y)

combined_df = combined_df.withColumn('match',whos_who_match(F.col('name'),F.col('name_proxy')))
#### 20 records
combined_df.show()

+----------------+---------------+-----+
|            name|     name_proxy|match|
+----------------+---------------+-----+
|       Luc Krier|       J. Thorn|false|
|       Luc Krier|     Ben Weller|false|
|       Luc Krier|       L. Krier| true|
|    Jeanny Thorn|       J. Thorn| true|
|    Jeanny Thorn|     Ben Weller|false|
|    Jeanny Thorn|       L. Krier|false|
| Teddy E Beecher|       J. Thorn|false|
| Teddy E Beecher|     Ben Weller|false|
| Teddy E Beecher|       L. Krier|false|
|       Luc Krier|     J.M. Thorn|false|
|       Luc Krier|    Liam Muller|false|
|       Luc Krier|Meindert Tholen|false|
|    Jeanny Thorn|     J.M. Thorn|false|
|    Jeanny Thorn|    Liam Muller|false|
|    Jeanny Thorn|Meindert Tholen|false|
| Teddy E Beecher|     J.M. Thorn|false|
| Teddy E Beecher|    Liam Muller|false|
| Teddy E Beecher|Meindert Tholen|false|
|Philippe Schauss|       J. Thorn|false|
|Philippe Schauss|     Ben Weller|false|
+----------------+---------------+-----+
```

#### Filter

```
combined_df.filter(F.col('match') == True).show()

+-----------------+---------------+-----+
|             name|     name_proxy|match|
+-----------------+---------------+-----+
|        Luc Krier|       L. Krier| true|
|     Jeanny Thorn|       J. Thorn| true|
|Meindert I Tholen|Meindert Tholen| true|
+-----------------+---------------+-----+
```

Comment: yeah , the cross join will result in a huge blow up of your dataset , I tried to orderBy before doing so , but no luck , if you can join based on a more common key , the resultant dataset will reduce significantly

Comment: not sure how much of a benefit it would have , but yeah cab convert the udf to a pandas udf as well

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I change the `udf` to a `pandas_udf` because this is very slow? Can you show me an example how to change it to a 'pandas_udf` ?

Comment: Can you show me an example how to change it to a 'pandas_udf` ?

Comment: Updated the answer , added Pandas UDF as well , doe let me know the timing difference , also do upvote the answer if it helped you

Comment: Thank you very much. I won't be able to test it extensively in the next few days due to obligations but I'll let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: I've tested the `pandas_udf` but it's still to slow. Running for hours. Number of rows 55250 and 27900. I need to find another solution.

Comment: Yeah , it thought the same , your biggest enemy is the `CROSS JOIN` , reducing the comparisons with clever rules will do the trick